# How to send email with attachment using MimeMessage in asp.net core web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've tried with only simple text but i want to sent email with attachment.

```
    var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
    emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test","test@gmail.com"));
    emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Demo", "demo@gmail.com"));
    emailMessage.Subject = "Hello";
    emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("html") { Text = "Hi............" };
```

//**I want Attachment here with body text..**

```
    //Send Email.
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
            await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            await client.AuthenticateAsync("uid", "pass");
            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
    multipart.Add(new TextPart("html") { Text = "your body message"});

    // create an image attachment for the file located at path
    var attachment = new MimePart ("image", "gif") {
       ContentObject = new ContentObject (File.OpenRead (path), ContentEncoding.Default),
       ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition (ContentDisposition.Attachment),
       ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
       FileName = Path.GetFileName (path)
    };

    multipart.Add(attachment);
    emailMessage.Body = multipart;
```

For more detail, Please visit [here](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm)