# failed to add an attachment in MimeMessage (rotativa) for sending Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to send a (view page) pdf sending by email.but when I trying to add an attachment, I found an error below "Add". for that I can't successfully sending mail with attaching my view pdf.
Here is my code:

```
(Ordercontroller)

//other code


            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Test Project", "pt300@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("psm", "p689@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "Hi,this is demo email";
            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = "Hello,My First Demo Mail it is.Thanks",
            };

            //add attach
            var aa = new ViewAsPdf("Cart")
            {
                FileName = "Invoice.pdf",          //actually, I don't know why this filename is 
                                                    // "Invoice". I found this system on a website.

                PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
            };
         
            message.Attachments.Add(aa);

            //end attach
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                client.Authenticate("pt300@gmail.com", "MyPassword");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);

            }

//other code
```

and these controller's view I trying to pdf and send by mail:

```
(HomeController)

  public ActionResult Cart()
        {
            List<Product> products = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Product>>("products");
            if (products == null)
            {
                products = new List<Product>();
            }
            return View(products);
        }
```

in OrderController I found an error.

[image]

how I will solve this problem and successfully send my view's pdf by mail.please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email with attachment using MimeMessage in asp.net core web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392811/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-using-mimemessage-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: @SirRufo here solution used just attachment anything. but I want to send mail cart.cshtml in pdf format.

Comment: if you consider ```var aa = new ViewAsPdf("Cart")``` line, here I want cart.cshtml pdf format and then send it by mail. but problem doing "Add" which output I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Attachments*** is a ***MimeMessage*** property that has no such method ***Add***, so here comes the error. To add the attachments you should create a [BodyBuilder](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_BodyBuilder.htm) object before, with this class you will be able to add new attachments (each one of them as byte array), usign ***Attachments*** Property and its ***Add*** method, but always related to ***BodyBuilder***, not to ***MimeMessage***.

Please, take a look to the answer given here, as I guess is what you are looking for:
[.net Core Mailkit send attachement from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413816/net-core-mailkit-send-attachement-from-array)

Or check another example here:
https://www.taithienbo.com/send-email-with-attachments-using-mailkit-for-net-core/

In addition, you could get Rotativa PDF as byte array usign this code:

```
var rotativaAction = new ViewAsPdf("Cart")
{
    FileName = "Invoice.pdf",   // You can change this file name to set whatever you want
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
};

byte[] fileAttachmetByteArray = rotativaAction.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
```

Once you have generated your PDF as a byte array using Rotativa, guessing you have stored the result in a variable called `fileAttachmentByteArray` (as stated in the previous code sample), you must simply send this variable (the byte array) to the ***Add*** method of the ***BodyBuilder***, as the second parameter (first is the attachement file name, which is completely free to use the name you prefer), and then set ***Mime Message*** ***Body***, usign the ***BodyBuilder*** you have worked with.

So, to explain the process in steps:

1. On the first line you create a BodyBuilder variable, and initialize it, using the text you want as body for the email.
2. Then, you call ***Add*** method to add a new attachment, sending to it the file name  you wish and your previously created bye array
3. Finally, you asign the value to the ***Body*** property of your Mime Message

And your code should look like this:

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = "yourBodyMessage" };   // Change "yourBodyMessage" to the email body you desire
builder.Attachments.Add("filename", fileAttachmentByteArray);   // Once again, you can change this "filename" to set whatever you want
mimeMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();   // Assuming mimeMessage is the same variable you provided in your code
```

Comment: now I understand that I have to follow and add attachment according to your last code. I would be grateful if you update your code to add this attachment using the byte array.

Comment: Hi @Shane Watson. Maybe I posted the information in the wrong order, I will edit the answer. Please, check if this is the process flow is clear if this is what you are asking for. Thanks!